# MPMoviePlayerController orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play movie using remote video URL. Is it possible to find it out in which device orientation video is taken whether protrait or landscape? According to that i will set portrait frame and landscape frame. 
Please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing two frames to accommodate video control and thumbnail image, i set the following settings to thumbnail image view. 
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;